# set of primes plus 1 contain multiples of every integer

Tags: prime-numbers

Saw a claim that for every natural number $j$, the set $\{ nj-1: n \ge 1 \} $ must contain at least one prime. Is that correct? If so, is there a simple proof? I can see that *at least one* can be easily extended to *infinitely many*, if the statement is correct.

Comment: I don't know if there's a simple proof, but Dirichlet's theorem gives you a much more general result

Comment: @D_S Thanks, I get that now.

Answer (score 1):

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32624/special-cases-of-dirichlets-theorem and the many links given there. In particular, I quote from Robin Chapman's answer:

...there is an elementary proof
that for each $n$ there are infinitely many primes $p$
with $p\equiv1$ (mod $n$). There is an also an elementary
proof that for each $n$ there are infinitely many primes
$p$ with $p\equiv-1$ (mod $n$). This can be found in Nagell's
*Introduction to Number Theory* section 50 in the second
edition.

EDIT. One of the links at the mathoverflow question leads to Keith Conrad's paper, [Euclidean proofs of Dirichlet's Theorem](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/dirichleteuclid.pdf). Conrad cites a theorem of Schur: if $a^2\equiv1\bmod m$, then a Euclidean polynomial for $a\bmod m$ exists (he also cites a theorem of Murty: if there is a Euclidean polynomial for $a\bmod m$, then $a^2\equiv1\bmod m$). The Schur citation is Uber die Existenz unendlich vieler Primzahlen in einigen speziellen arithmetischen Progressionen, Sitzungber. Berliner Math. Ges. 11 (1912), 40–50.

MORE EDIT. I had a look at the proof in Nagell. The good news, it doesn't use anything beyond introductory Number Theory, Binomial Theorem, and arithmetic of complex numbers. Bad news, it's three pages long, and that's not counting a page for the proof of one of the earlier theorems used in the proof. So, I'm not inclined to write it out here.

Comment: If the proof is simple it would be nice to include it in your answer.

Comment: @orlp, elementary $\ne$ simple. But let me encourage you to track down a copy of Nagell's book and see whether you would like to post an answer with the proof.

Comment: The question asked for a simple proof though. So even if it's elementary, if it's not simple (although it's subjective what exactly can be considered simple) it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @orlp: While I did ask for a simple proof, I guess a standard one does fine!

Comment: @orlp, if after all these years the only proof anyone can point to is not simple, that answers the question in the negative. At least, it would strongly suggest that there is no simple proof. Again I encourage you to follow the pointers I've given, and see for yourself what the situation is.